# parse some infomation going through socket

Tags: .net, sockets

My task is to create some kind of proxy server which automaticaly changes all links on any web-site.

My main problem is that i even don't know how to describe my question to google it.

So, now i have working proxy

```
        while (true)
        {
            if (myTCP.Pending())
            {
                using (var myClient = myTCP.AcceptSocket())
                {
                    if (myClient.Connected)
                    {
                        var httpRequest = ShitConverter.ReadToEnd(myClient);
                        var httpRequestString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(httpRequest);
                        var myReg = new Regex(@"Host: (((?<host>.+?):(?<port>\d+?))|(?<host>.+?))\s+", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                        var m = myReg.Match(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(httpRequest));
                        var host = m.Groups["host"].Value;
                        var port = 0;
                        if (!int.TryParse(m.Groups["port"].Value, out port))
                        {
                            port = 80;
                        }
                        var myIPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(host);
                        var myIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(myIPHostEntry.AddressList[0],port);                          
                    using (var myReroutingSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
                        {
                            myReroutingSocket.Connect(myIPEndPoint);
                            if (myReroutingSocket.Send(httpRequest, httpRequest.Length, SocketFlags.None) !=
                                httpRequest.Length)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Sending error");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var httpResponse = StConverter.ReadToEnd(myReroutingSocket);
                                var httpStringResponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(httpResponse);
                                myClient.Send(httpResponse, httpResponse.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }`
```

Now i need to find where is all HTML stuff which browser gonna display me. 
I think that `httpResponse` variable holding it, but I don't know how interprete all these bytes i've got. String version of httpResponse contains something like

```
??\u0019\u001c\f???&?\u0002K?~???
```

So i really appreciate any help and guidance in my problem.

Comment: I would try [FiddlerCore](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore)

Comment: thank for advice, i'll try it :)